# rails coffeescript RESTful edit form submission not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, coffeescript

In the controller's coffeescript file I have

```
jQuery ->
    billing_account.setupForm()

billing_account =
    setupForm: ->
        $('#new_billing_account').submit ->
```

And, the `$('#new_billing_account').submit` function is called when a *new* resource is created. However, when I *edit* a resource `$('#new_billing_account').submit` is not longer called when the form is submitted; however, the form is indeed submitted.

I tried adding different form name prefixes but neither `$('#update_billing_account').submit` nor `$('#edit_billing_account').submit` are called.

How do I get edit/update to call the same (or any) form setup code?

I'm using a default RESTful generated resource scaffold with Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to change `new_billing_account` to whatever the id of the form is (look at the generated html). By default rails sets the id on an edit form to `edit_model_name_id, for example when editing the`BillingAccount`with id 456, the form would have id`edit_billing_account_456`.

You can pass extra options to form for to force the id to something constant, or you can use the fact that the form's class will be set to `edit_brand` (i.e. change your selector to `$('form.edit_billing_account')`